# why can't I find my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, unix, aptitude

I did updatedb.
I did locate my.cnf

But I cannot find it? Nothing.

(I installed MYSQL using aptitude install mysql-server, and mysql does work right now.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What is your operating system ? On Debian Linux, it is located on /etc/mysql/my.cnf. If your cannot find it, you can create one from scratch using this [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html).

Comment: Do I just make the file and put it inside /etc/mysql/my.cnf? MYSQL will automatically use that?

Comment: If you use Debian Linux or something similar, check the right location in the file /etc/init.d/mysql. In my case I can see CONF=/etc/mysql/my.cnf on the line 25.

Answer (score 8):

You can try following command:

`find /etc -name *.cnf`

it will show you all locations of *.cnf files

Comment: Yes. That should find it. He may have to do a "sudo find /etc -name *.cnf" though.

Comment: you are a hero. your answer proved to be a great start for me to solve an issue i have been stuck for ages. :)

Answer (score 0):

locate will only print files in directories that you can read.

Also, when you say you did updatedb, did you run

`sudo /etc/cron.daily/slocate`

If not, then probably what you did run wasn't equivalent.  (The default locate program on Debian/Ubuntu these days is mlocate).

Answer (score 0):

create a configuration file
MySQL provides several configuration methods but, in general, it is easiest to to create a my.ini file in the mysql folder. There are hundreds of options to tweak MySQL to your exact requirements, but the simplest my.ini file is:

```
[mysqld]
# installation directory
basedir="C:/mysql/"

# data directory
datadir="D:/MySQLdata/"
```